# How to build a theme similar to “Brikit Theme Press for Confluence”

Tags: jira, confluence

I need to build a theme for Confluence and it will be used for our intranet website. At Atlassian marketplace, I found that that

Brikit Theme Press for Confluence: 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=Brikit%20Theme%20Press

is close to what I need. By "close", I mean its ability to customize, not its visual look and feel. I would like to learn/know how it was implemented.

I am a Java developer and new to Confluence/Jira. How can I build a custom theme similar to "Brikit Theme Press for Confluence"? The following tutorial is too simple:

Writing a Confluence Theme: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/tutorials/writing-a-confluence-theme?_ga=1.265485647.1517411526.1490638576

Comment: You just need to learn how to work with Atlassian SDK. There is no step by step document but the SDK itself not that difficult.

Comment: Saleh, thanks for your input!